# Trying to parse a JSON from a given url

Tags: javascript, html, json, http

So I've been given a url: "http://theossrv2.epfl.ch/aiida_assignment2/api/points/", and I've been trying to get a JSON from this url. Here's what I've done so far:

```
var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            callback(null, xhr.response);
        } else {
            callback(status, xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

getJSON('http://theossrv2.epfl.ch/aiida_assignment2/api/points/',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err !== null) {
            alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
        } else {
            alert('Your max_x: ' + data.max_x);
        }
    });
```

For now, I'm just putting max_x in an alert box, just to see if I recovered it (which seems to be the case). But when I'm trying to recover the data in "circles" (namely the x or y coordinates or even the id), I get "undefined" (in the alert box), and I do not understand why, nor how I can actually recover the data stored in "circles".

The thing is, I want to be able to parse the JSON I get from this url, because I need to draw these circles on a canvas, and I can't do that if I cannot recover those coordinates.

I hope I've been clear enough. Please note that I'm only a beginner when it comes to coding in JS and HTML in general, so if there is smth that you find obvious, that might not be the case for me.

Comment: what do you get if you use `data.circles[0].x`

Comment: That Javascript code is served from this domain: `theossrv2.epfl.ch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data variable contains object with the following keys:

```
{
    circles: [ ... ],
    range: {
        max_x: 300,
        ...
    }
}
```

So, in order to get `max_x`, you need to read `data.range.max_x` property instead of just `data.max_x`.

As for data in `circles`, you'll have array of objects in `data.circles`, so you can iterate over it using `for` loop for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.circles.length; i++) {
    // data.circles[i] contains object with { id, x, y } properties
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems much more clear now. Just a question though. Say I have ` data.circles[i] ` which (as you told me ) is an object, how do I get the id or xy coordinates ?

Comment: I'm sorry if that seems obvious to you, but my initial idea was to create instances of a class I've written on my own (a class that has id, x and y as attributes, and some other methods, such as getX, ... ) . But I think that since, as you pointed out, I already get objects, there is no need for me to create some new ones.

Comment: @Skyris simply use the same notation as you use to get `max_x` property from `range` object: `data.circles[i].id`, `data.circles[i].x`, `data.circles[i].y`

Answer (score 0):

`data` returned from the server is actually an object having key `circles` & `range` and `max_x` is a property of `range` key. Which you can get like:

```
alert('Your max_x: ' + data.range.max_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it sending object of

```
{
 "circles": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "x": 52.47599289586478,
    "y": 249.77824107448706
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 281.34253692626953,
    "y": 281.34253692626953
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "x": 99.59752655029297,
    "y": 99.36786252693544
  }
],
 "range": {
  "max_x": 300,
  "max_y": 300,
  "min_x": 0,
  "min_y": 0
 }
}
```

so you need `data.range.max_x`